# Can we set ListDictionary property from the page markup?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private ListDictionary parameters;
public ListDictionary Parameters
{
    get
    {
        if (parameters == null) parameters = new ListDictionary();
        return parameters;
    }
    set
    {
        if (parameters == null) parameters = new ListDictionary();
        parameters = value;
    }
}
```

can i set such property in the markup of ASP.NET page? and how?

i mean something like `<uc1:CustomControl Parameters="?"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `[System.ComponentModel.Category("Settings")]`, then a property will appear in markup IntelliSense

I think you need a workaround because all values in markup are strings so you need to parse them into your specific class:

```
<uc1:CustomControl Parameters="foo,bar" />

[Category("Settings")]
public string Parameters
{
    set
    {
        var arr = String.Split(",", value).Select(p => p.Trim());
        if (parameters == null) parameters = new ListDictionary();
        foreach (string p in arr)
            parameters.Add(p);

    }
}
```

or use inline (aka code block), e.g.:

```
<%= new ListDictionary { "foo", "bar " } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this statement in the [code block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx) IMHO.